# Android rate App Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I have an App (Mini file manager) on my phone that has a button "Rate it 5 Stars" and clicking this button launches the market and fills in a 5 star rating automatically. How do I achieve this in my App? Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really? I doubt this. Maybe you already rated that app 5 stars?

Comment: lol! I think you are right, tried changing it to 3 stars and re-trying doesn't work.